# Weblogic 12.1.3 PrivilegedActions class not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic

i create a simple we project that call a jms queue and put in a message.

Here the code:

```
public class QueueSend
{
 // Defines the JNDI context factory.
 public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";

 // Defines the JMS context factory.
 public final static String JMS_FACTORY="jms/MyConnectionFactory";

 // Defines the queue.
 public final static String QUEUE="jms/MyTestQueue";

 private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
 private QueueConnection qcon;
 private QueueSession qsession;
 private QueueSender qsender;
 private Queue queue;
 private TextMessage msg;

 /**
  * Creates all the necessary objects for sending
  * messages to a JMS queue.
  *
  * @param ctx JNDI initial context
  * @param queueName name of queue
  * @exception NamingException if operation cannot be performed
  * @exception JMSException if JMS fails to initialize due to internal error
  */
 public void init(Context ctx, String queueName)
    throws NamingException, JMSException
 {
    qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
    qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
    qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);
    msg = qsession.createTextMessage();
    qcon.start();
 }

 /**
  * Sends a message to a JMS queue.
  *
  * @param message  message to be sent
  * @exception JMSException if JMS fails to send message due to internal error
  */
 public void send(String message) throws JMSException {
    msg.setText(message);
    qsender.send(msg);
 }

 /**
  * Closes JMS objects.
  * @exception JMSException if JMS fails to close objects due to internal error
  */
 public void close() throws JMSException {
    qsender.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
 }
/** main() method.
 *
 * @param args WebLogic Server URL
 * @exception Exception if operation fails
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Context ic = getInitialContext("t3://localhost:7001");
    QueueSend qs = new QueueSend();
    qs.init(ic, QUEUE);
    readAndSend(qs);
    qs.close();
 }

 private static void readAndSend(QueueSend qs)
    throws IOException, JMSException
 {

       qs.send("ciao");
       System.out.println("JMS Message Sent: ciao \n");


 }

 private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url)
    throws NamingException
 {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    return new InitialContext(env);
 }
}
```

When i launch the main, i have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/service/PrivilegedActions
    at weblogic.jndi.WLSJNDIEnvironmentImpl.<clinit>(WLSJNDIEnvironmentImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.JNDIEnvironment.getJNDIEnvironment(JNDIEnvironment.java:37)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:92)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at test.QueueSend.getInitialContext(QueueSend.java:109)
    at test.QueueSend.main(QueueSend.java:86)
```

I have founded, with google, that the **PrivilegedActions** is in the weblogic.security.service (**weblogic-api.jar**; i have included this jar in my project but internally it has not this class) but is only a problem of the 12.1.3 version?

Thanks for the response

Comment: same problem with weblogic 12.2.1

Comment: I have a same problem with Weblogic 12.1.3. Which jar files exactly did you add to your project? I could not find weblogic-api.jar. There is just a wls-api.jar. I added wls-api.jar and weblogic.jar to my classpath, but the problem exists yet.

Comment: I'm using weblogic 12.1.3 I finally found the desired jar file. It is located here: `wlserver\modules\com.oracle.css.weblogic.security.wls_7.1.0.0.jar`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

I have updated to 12.2.1 and generated a `wlfullclient.jar`. I have added it to Build Library Path and removed the WebLogic Libraries.