# Bare minimum code for a JMS producer

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I am really struggling to get a working bare minimum code for a JMS producer, I have got my WL JMS server up and running and ready to test it using a JMS client but for creating a client I am having issues with use of initial context factory i.e. `env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");`. I have tried almost all code, using WL initial context factory, oracle j2ee initial context factory (`env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "oracle.j2ee.rmi.RMIInitialContextFactory");`) but I always get no class definition found exception when I run my code. For example, for below code I get no class definition found exception.

I am trying to run client as a standalone Java program. I understand the exception and have tried to add the relevant JAR for example when I was using WL initial context factory then I placed WL full client JAR in the classpath but still I am not able to overcome this no class def found exception.

Could someone please link to some repository or blog or provide me a bare minimum "working" JMS producer, or point on what wrong I am doing.

Please note that my JMS server is WL, and I am trying to create a simple JMS client, without using ActiveMQ library, but I am tagging the ActiveMQ as well so that it can get more attention but if anyone thinks it is wrong then please let me know and I will delete ActiveMQ  tag, or please feel free to delete yourself.

**My client example:**

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class JmsProducerQueueClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, JMSException {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Create JNDI Context");
            Context context = getInitialContext();

            System.out.println("Get connection facory");
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("/com/jms/ms1/cf1");

            System.out.println("Create connection");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

            System.out.println("Create session");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            System.out.println("Lookup queue");
            Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("/com/jms/ms1/q1");

            System.out.println("Start connection");
            connection.start();

            System.out.println("Create producer");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

            System.out.println("Create hello world message");
            Message hellowWorldText = session.createTextMessage("Hello World!");

            System.out.println("Send hello world message");

            producer.send(hellowWorldText);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("close the connection");
                connection.close();
            }
        }

    }

    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        //env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "oracle.j2ee.rmi.RMIInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:6007");
        Context context = new InitialContext(env);
        return context;
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
Create JNDI Context
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/service/PrivilegedActions
    at weblogic.jndi.WLSJNDIEnvironmentImpl.<clinit>(WLSJNDIEnvironmentImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.JNDIEnvironment.getJNDIEnvironment(JNDIEnvironment.java:37)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:92)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at com.learning.so.question.jms.queue.producerconsumer.JmsProducerQueueClient.getInitialContext(JmsProducerQueueClient.java:62)
    at com.learning.so.question.jms.queue.producerconsumer.JmsProducerQueueClient.main(JmsProducerQueueClient.java:22)
```

Comment: Everything should be bundled in wlfullclient.jar. What is the version of weblogic?

Comment: I am using WL 12c

Comment: OK. Use the wlthint3client instead of wlfullclient. And why do you use tcp instead of t3 protocol?

Comment: @Rouliboy I tried but now I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/service/PrivilegedActions`, I will check the answer of @Axel for this exception

Comment: Did you try with t3 protocol? Did you try with `wlthint3client`?

Comment: @Rouliboy I tried with `wlthint3client`, also with T3 protocol, whatever I try in the end I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/service/PrivilegedActions`, I even tried to generate a full WL client JAR as suggested by Axel but still nothing works. I am so much surprised and frustated by this.

Comment: @Rouliboy Do you have any working standalone Java code of JMS producer/consumer, including all JARs?

Comment: I posted an answer :-)

Comment: @Rouliboy Thank you very much for posting that helpful answer, please give me some time, I will check and come back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make your code work on my side, so I think that your problem comes from a missing dependency, pretty sure from the weblgogic client. May be the way you packaged your application is the problem.

So I will expose what I did, just using my own queue name et factory name.

Note that this test has been done on **WLS 12.1.3.**

### Weblogic client

Firstly I created a maven dependency from the `wlthint3client.jar` that can be found on weblogic server, in `${ORACLE_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib` using the `mvn install:install-file` command :

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=wlthint3client.jar -DgroupId=weblogic -DartifactId=wlthint3client -Dversion=12.1.3.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar

With that, I can now use the following dependency in all my maven projects :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### Weblogic JMS Factory and Queue

Then I created a `JMSXAFactory` Factory and a `test` JMS Queue on weblogic side.

### JMS Producer project

Then I created the maven project. Here is the `pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.jvi.weblogic.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>jms-producer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>jms-producer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
      <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the `App` class code :

```
package org.jvi.weblogic.jms;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public final static String JNDI_FACTORY = "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";

    public final static String  URL = "t3://localhost:7001";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws NamingException, JMSException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Create JNDI Context");
            Context context = getInitialContext();

            System.out.println("Get connection facory");
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("JMSXAFactory");

            System.out.println("Create connection");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

            System.out.println("Create session");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            System.out.println("Lookup queue");
            Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("test");

            System.out.println("Start connection");
            connection.start();

            System.out.println("Create producer");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

            System.out.println("Create hello world message");
            Message hellowWorldText = session.createTextMessage("Hello World!");

            System.out.println("Send hello world message");

            producer.send(hellowWorldText);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("close the connection");
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException
            {
              Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
              env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
              env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, URL);
              return new InitialContext(env);
            }
}
```

Then when I launch the application through command line :

```
java -cp jms-producer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.jvi.weblogic.jms.App
```

### Result

After launching this command, I can see that message is correctly produced in `test` queue :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this helpful answer, please give me some time, I will check and come back to you.

Comment: More problems buddy, I didn't know Maven, I somehow got to run the Maven command, installed maven and then from the location where I had my pom.xml (with content from your answer), I executed the command you mentioned but ended up in failed run, I got this error  - `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project jms-producer: The parameters 'file' for
 goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I ran the command line this `C:\ApacheFoundation\localRepository>mvn install:install-file`, and at "C:\ApacheFoundation\localRepository" I had my pom.xml with the content you had mentioned. Did I miss anything or what else I need to do for running maven successfully?

Comment: Are you running from WL installation or Java code location, I just ran the updated command but still I get same error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project jms-producer: The specified file 'C:\Ap
acheFoundation\localRepository\wlthint3client.jar' not exists -> [Help 1]`

Comment: you run this command from where is located the `wlthint3client.jar` jar

Comment: Ok, I am executing from there, let see what happens

Comment: Ok, I got this JAR generated - `wlthint3client-12.1.3.0.0.jar` but JAR in your Java command is `jms-producer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: No, you're mistaken : `wlthint3client-12.1.3.0.0.jar` is the weblogic client jar (used as a dependency in the App), while `jms-producer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is the standalone jar which is launched to produce a JMS message on a weblogic JMS queue.

Comment: I included `wlthint3client-12.1.3.0.0.jar` WL JAR in my classpath and run my program, I again got same error - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/service/PrivilegedActions` .. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Please share your code. Can you put your project on a server? I will take a look.

Comment: Code is exactly same which I mentioned in my question, I am running from Eclipse, and in my build path I included that WL JAR, that's it.

Comment: Hold on, I think I got the problem, it was a bloody Eclipse problem I guess, I executed my code from command line by including your JAR in the classpath and I am getting `Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:6007:` exception which means my java execution is fine, first time I am happy to see an exception :) I cannot thank you enough for your time and help on this one. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: Seriously mate. And I will **never** forgive and forget Eclipse for this one, I just ran my code again from command line and this time with `wlthint3client.jar` (which you very initially mentioned) and it is also working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok, but you are currently missing a class in your classpath: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/service/PrivilegedActions

check here, this might have the answer: [Weblogic 12.1.3 PrivilegedActions class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794504/weblogic-12-1-3-privilegedactions-class-not-found)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to generate this JAR but I am getting some error .. Is some repository from where I can download `wlfullclient.jar` JAR?

Comment: Hold on looks like I will get.

Comment: I am seeing no end this problem, I generated the WL full JAR using process mentioned here but still I get error https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/client/jarbuilder.html

Comment: Do you have any working standalone Java code of JMS producer/consumer, including all JARs?